# Firing a change event from the first, default select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of options but as expected the first option in the list won't fire the change event call. I was wondering how to get this to fire without doing a manual `trigger()` if at all possible.

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  console.log($(e.target).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have to trigger it...

Comment: Trigger it in what way?

Comment: You have to execute the code in some manner.... Either you call trigger on the first select, or you manually call the code that it is executing.

Comment: I ask because there would be no way to detect the first option on change if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Trigger it when the select is rendered. Makes little sense to know if someone reselected something since it did not change.

Comment: Are you trying to have it fire immediately  when rendered or like if someone selects that entry?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid a manual `trigger()` call? And FYI, the [select event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select) is for selecting text, not select elements.

Comment: FYI: onselect is NOT correct.... that is selecting text....

Comment: Unfortunately the I have to fire it on change. In my real world project the options have urls as values and on change it takes them there. Just couldn't point that out in my example because I'm a little incapacitated at the moment.

Comment: You're right @epascarello. Changed it to, `change()`.

Comment: So why is there not a "Select XYZ" text on top?

Comment: That comment about url redirection was the most important part and should be in the question

Comment: @CarlEdwards I wouldn't redirect automatically on change. Some prefer navigating using tab + arrows. Changing the value with arrows will fire the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you can not fire it on page load since the select takes the user to a new location, that means you only have two thing you can do.

First is to add a select option on top so user has to pick something. That way the change event will fire since they have to pick what is not default.

```
<option value="">Pick your favorite cheese</option>
```

or your section option is to use `blur`, instead of `change`. The issue with using blur is the user has to remove focus from it in order for it to fire.

Comment: Upvote : First option is certainly the way to go however, the second one isn't great concerning the user experience.